# relationship tables in sequelise

Tags: sequelize.js

I have 3 tables:`(student,elective,student_elective)`

```
student:
id,
name,

elective:
id,
name,
credits,
curriculum_id,

student_elective:
student_id,
elective_id,
subject_id,
preference_No,
status
```

`{student_id, elective_id, subject_id }`:make primary key,
`{student_id,elective_id , preference_No }`: should be unique,
 in student elective

Here student_elective is a relation table between elective and student.
How are we supposed to do it in sequelize?

Comment: You're after "belongsToMany" which is described in the docs at http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/docs/associations/#belongs-to-many-associations